# “error: stray '\342' ”, “stray '\200' ”, “stray '\213' ” in C compiling

Tags: c

Here is my code

```
int main()​
{
    float avg, age[] = { 23.4, 55, 22.6, 3, 40.5, 18 };
    avg = average(age); /* Only name of array is passed as argument. */
    printf("Average age=%.2f", avg);
    return 0;
}
```

Compilation error in `int main()`:

```
error: stray '\342' in program
error: stray '\200' in program
error: stray '\213' in program
```

Comment: Show us the error message.

Comment: And the compilation statement, too.

Comment: Are you copying code from MS Word?

Comment: No copy from another

Comment: It seems to be a UTF-8 byte sequence for a BOM character, a zero-width space at the begin of the file to let Notepad on Windows detect it is a UTF-8 text file. With another editor like Notepad++ you can save it as UTF-8 without BOM. Or a couple of backspaces deleting the first char of the text. Maybe it would help to set the projects encoding to UTF-8 too; the compiler for instance.

Comment: @JoopEggen the BOM isn't a zero-width space, afaik.

Comment: I believe you should set Codeblocks Settings -> Editor -> Other settings tab -> Use encoding when opening files: UTF-8. And then check "use this encoding as fallback encoding".

Comment: @FelixPalmen Wikipedia cited: _If the BOM (Byte Order Mark) character appears in the middle of a data stream, Unicode says it should be interpreted as a "zero-width non-breaking space."_ My description was intended to hint that the character is not seen, a ghost.

Comment: And please don't dump us with screen shots of compiler messages. Their text suffices.

Comment: @JoopEggen That's the wrong way around. The BOM is a different sequence and this just tells it should be seen as whitespace when appearing somewhere in the middle. The character codes in the error message are not the BOM.

Comment: @FelixPalmen Apologies, I have checked the values, and they are not of a BOM. So there must be special chars. Could happen via an included macro too.

Comment: @JoopEggen it's an *actual* "zero width space" here. But yes, a BOM would lead to a very similar error.

Comment: This is a duplicate. The canonical is *[Compilation error: stray ‘\302’ in program, etc.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19198332)*.

Comment: Though the canonical is currently lacking *comprehensive* answers.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Compilation error: stray ‘\302’ in program, etc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19198332/compilation-error-stray-302-in-program-etc)

Comment: This is a ***very*** common error when copying code from web pages, [PDF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Document_Format) documents, through chat (e.g. [Skype Chat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Features_of_Skype#Skype_chat) or [Facebook Messenger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facebook_Messenger)), etc. The canonical question is *[Compilation error: stray ‘\302’ in program, etc.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19198332)*.

Answer (score 8):

You have "crap characters" in your source file.

`\342 \200 \213` is octal for 0xE2 0x80 0x8B which is a *[zero width space](https://www.utf8-chartable.de/unicode-utf8-table.pl?start=8192&number=128)* in UTF-8 (Unicode `U+200B`), something no C compiler can make sense of (and something you can't see, zero-width after all, when UTF-8 is displayed correctly).

-> Use a text or code editor (even Windows' [Notepad](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Notepad_%28software%29) should do, if not saving as UTF-8, but any other editor would be better) and/or an integrated development environment to write your code. Don't ever use word processors or the like, that might introduce unwanted characters.

Comment: How do you remember the exact byte sequence of that zero-width-space?

Comment: @iBug convert octal to hex and google for the hex? With such a sequence of `>0x7f` characters, it's pretty obvious it's an UTF-8 sequence.

Comment: *"(even windows' "notepad" should do)"* Unfortunately, if you save file as UTF-8 it will include BOM too without telling you. Windows Notepad is so crap that it should not be used at all.

Comment: @user694733 well, the problem *here* wasn't a BOM, but good to know ... this would of course lead to a *similar* problem.

Comment: It is usually not caused by using word processors, but by copy-pasting code from web pages, PDF files, or chat (e.g. Skype Chat).

Answer (score 1):

This seem to be a problem with bad characters in your code. Characters that are non-printable like ╚ or something. Open your code for example in Notepad++, select menu option to view all characters, menu *View* → *Show invisible characters* → *Show all characters* and remove any bad characters from your code.

Comment: This will not help with zero width space (U+200B) that seems [to be the case here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47434802/error-stray-342-stray-200-stray-213-in-c-compiling/47434894#47434894). However, some code editors can do Unicode code point search and replace (e.g., [Notepad++](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Notepad%2B%2B)).

Comment: To be more precise, in this case, use `\x{200B}` in a regular expression search.

Answer (score 1):

The code **looks** fine.

According to my personal experience, `stray '\xxx'` is often caused by using invalid characters in your code (except in string literals), which happens more frequently if your language is not English.

For example, this code generates such an error:

```
int main（）｛return 0；｝
```

I can't find what's wrong, so my only suggestion is **make sure your IME is switched to English, then type the code again**.

Comment: Or by copying code from web pages, PDF files, or through chat, like Skype Chat.

Answer (score 1):

Use the following website. It will show you bad characters and then remove them:

*[View non-printable Unicode characters](https://www.soscisurvey.de/tools/view-chars.php)*